# I need a regex to replace all onclick etc from html code?

Tags: php, regex

Here is my function

I can't get the regex right that will remove on* attributes

```
public function removeUnsafeAttributes($input, $validTags = '')
{
    $regex = "";
    return preg_replace($regex,strip_tags($input, $validTags));
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
/on[A-Za-z]*?\=\".*?\"/
```

Comment: You don't need to escape = and ". So `/on[A-Za-z]*?=".*?"/` or even `/on[A-Za-z]*=".*"/U` will do the same.